# The plot is not displayed on my R shiny app

Tags: shiny

I am trying to make a Shiny app that generates plot of (sample size) vs. (power). My app correctly displays all the options for user input, but it fails to display the plot that I want the system to generate.

Could you help me with this? Below are my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("diagType", "Diagnosis Outcome of Interest:", c("Cancer", "Sepsis", "SIRS")),
    selectInput("alpha", "Significance Level:", c("0.05", "0.01", "0.001")),
    conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'Cancer'",
                sliderInput("bin1", label = "Cut off level for TK:", min=1, max=20, value=10),
                sliderInput("bin2", label = "Cut off level for AGE:", min=1, max=12, value=6),
                sliderInput("bin3", label = "Cut off level for BW:", min=1, max=40, value=20)),
   conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'Sepsis'",
                sliderInput("bin4", label = "Cut off level for CRP:", min=1, max=45, value=22.5),
                sliderInput("bin5", label = "Cut off level for WBC:", min=1, max=25, value=12.5),
                sliderInput("bin6", label = "Cut off level for Temp:", min=100, max=105, value=103)),
   conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'SIRS'",
                sliderInput("bin7", label = "Cut off level for CNP:", min=1, max=16, value=8),
                sliderInput("bin8", label = "Cut off level for Pulse:", min=95, max=180, value=135)),

    plotOutput("plot")
)


output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$diagType=='Cancer'){
       d <- data()
       plot(d$power.vec, d$cancer.sample.size)
       }
 })
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
        if (input$diagType=='Sepsis'){
        d <- data()
       plot(d$power.vec, d$sepsis.sample.size)
      }
 })
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$diagType=='SIRS'){
       d <- data()
       plot(d$power.vec, d$SIRS.sample.size)
      }
   })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have included `ui <- fluidPage`  and `shinyApp(ui, server)` I am going to assume this is your full code?
I don't see your server function and the data selection part. Can you include that?

I simplified your code and use `cars` data for the graph and it worked for me. I think the issue is between your drop down menu and the data generation `d <- data()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("diagType", "Diagnosis Outcome of Interest:", c("Cancer", "Sepsis", "SIRS")),
  selectInput("alpha", "Significance Level:", c("0.05", "0.01", "0.001")),
  conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'Cancer'",
                    sliderInput("bin1", label = "Cut off level for TK:", min=1, max=20, value=10),
                    sliderInput("bin2", label = "Cut off level for AGE:", min=1, max=12, value=6),
                    sliderInput("bin3", label = "Cut off level for BW:", min=1, max=40, value=20)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$diagType=="Cancer"){
      d <- cars
      plot(d$speed, d$dist)
    }
   })
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```